# Is any simpler way to plot GeoPandas data in Altair chart?

Tags: geopandas, altair

The basic way to display `GeoDataFrame` in `Altair`:

```py
import altair as alt
import geopandas as gpd

alt.renderers.enable('notebook')

world = gpd.read_file(gpd.datasets.get_path('naturalearth_lowres'))

data  = alt.InlineData(values = world[world.continent=='Africa'].__geo_interface__, #geopandas to geojson
                       # root object type is "FeatureCollection" but we need its features
                       format = alt.DataFormat(property='features',type='json')) 
alt.Chart(data).mark_geoshape(
).encode( 
    color='properties.pop_est:Q', # GeoDataFrame fields are accessible through a "properties" object 
    tooltip=['properties.name:N','properties.pop_est:Q']
).properties( 

    width=500,
    height=300
)
```

[image: Result]

But it will crush if I add column with `Nan` or `DateTime` values.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. At first you can use `world = alt.utils.sanitize_dataframe(world)` to convert columns with JSON incompatible types.
2. Or you can use `gpdvega` module to simplify code.

```py
import altair as alt
import geopandas as gpd
import gpdvega 

alt.renderers.enable('notebook')

world = gpd.read_file(gpd.datasets.get_path('naturalearth_lowres'))

alt.Chart(world[world.continent=='Africa']).mark_geoshape(
).encode( 
    color='pop_est', 
    tooltip=['name','pop_est']
).properties( 
    width=500,
    height=300
)
```

[image: result]

Just `pip install gpdvega` and `import gpdvega`. `altair` will work with `GeoDataFrame` as usual `DataFrame`. See details in [documentation](https://iliatimofeev.github.io/gpdvega/)